# How to delete all files in a directory?

Tags: directory, autoit

My script :

```
#RequireAdmin
FileDelete("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\")
```

I want to delete all files in that directory. I also tried :

```
#RequireAdmin
DirRemove("C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\temp\")
```

But it's not working, any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for [`FileDelete()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileDelete.htm) is `FileDelete("filename")  ;not only directory!`. You can also [use wildcards for filename (`*` and `?`)](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/FileFindFirstFile.htm).

[`DirRemove()`](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/DirRemove.htm) works as follows: `DirRemove ( "path" [, recurse = 0] )`. With recurse=0 (default), deletes the folder, but only if it is empty. With recurse=1 removes files and subdirectories (like the DOS `DelTree` command).

Maybe you misunderstood the flag to use:

```
; Remove only the empty folder "Folder_path"
DirRemove("Folder_Path")

; Remove folder "Folder_Path" with all subfolder and all files within
DirRemove("Folder_Path", 1)
```

If this doesn't work it's a matter of system rights. If you want to delete files without deleting containing folder:

```
#include <Files.au3>

; Get all files in folder and delete them:
Local $aFilesInRoot = _FileListToArray("Your_Path", 1, True) ; 1=$FLTA_FILES = Return files only,  True=returns full path
For $i = 1 To $aFilesInRoot[0]
    FileDelete($aFilesInRoot[1])
Next

; Get all subfolders under root and delete them:
Local $aFolderInRoot = _FileListToArray("Your_Path", 2, True) ;2=$FLTA_FOLDERS = Return Folders only
For $i = 1 To $aFolderInRoot[0]
    DirRemove($aFolderInRoot[1], 1)
Next
```

But isn't it easier to remake the deleted folder after deleting all with only one command?